# Configure org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender with custom classloader

Tags: java, log4j, classloader, javassist

I have a java class which creates a custom classloader based on javassist class loader on start up and then run the real program class.
I'm getting the following error:

```
log4j:ERROR A "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" object is not assignable to a        
"org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.
log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by 
log4j:ERROR [javassist.Loader@6f97b10a] whereas object of type 
log4j:ERROR "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" was loaded by 
[java.net.URLClassLoader@5b414a8d].
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "stdout".
```

The problem is related to the fact that one object is created by the original classloader while the other is created by the custom one.
Is there a way to resolve this error?

Thanks in advance,
  Avner

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Please try to set -Dlog4j.ignoreTCL=true, hope it helps. a simular issue [about log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719218/classloading-issue-with-osgi)

Comment: still did not work for me :(. im using io.sentry:sentry-log4j2 but gonna fall back to io.sentry:sentry-log4j instead.

Comment: Does`t work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add **log4j.ignoreTCL**  in maven tomcat plugin configuration as shown in below

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
   <configuration>
      <port>${local.server.port}</port>
      <update>true</update>
      <systemProperties>
         <log4j.configurationFile>${user.dir}\conf\log4j2.xml</log4j.configurationFile>
         <log4j.ignoreTCL>true</log4j.ignoreTCL>
         <java.util.logging.manager>org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
      </systemProperties>
      <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```